# VS2013: Platform Toolkit doesn't include Windows SDK

Tags: winapi, directx, visual-studio-2013

I wen't into my project properties under `Platform Toolkit` and was hoping to find the Windows 8.1 SDK to select because I just installed the SDK on my system. However. I only have two options and Both are Visual Stuio 2013's.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? I am trying to learn D3D11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 (v120) is the correct toolset.  It's confusing naming, but the Windows 8.1 SDK includes the VS 2013 tools.